# Confusion about Feynman rules for free photon propagation

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics, probability, quantum-optics, propagator

In the book (and lecture series) "QED", Feynman gives a recipe for calculating the amplitude that a photon emitted from point A would be detected at point C.

The recipe is to sum the amplitudes for each path the photon may take. The amplitude for a given path (from A to C) is given by $$P(A \rightarrow C) \propto e^{-ikr}/r,$$ where $r$ is the distance from A to C.

This can also be extended to space-time by replacing the amplitude with the position-space propagator $$(\Delta x^2-\Delta t^2)^{-1}.$$

He then says that for a composite path, we may multiply the amplitudes, meaning that for any point B we should get:

$$P(A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C )= P(A \rightarrow B) \cdot P(B \rightarrow C).$$

This seems to be wrong. Let's call the distance from A to B "$r_1$" and the distance from B to C "$r_2$". Then the LHS is

$$P(A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C ) \propto1/\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2 -2 cos(\theta)}$$

where $\theta$ is the angel between the lines. but the RHS gives:

$$P(A \rightarrow B) \cdot P(B \rightarrow C) \propto1/(r_1*r_2).$$

Even the units don't match.

What am I missing?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which page? Which pages are the formulas listed? Specifically where do the first 2 eqs. come from?

Comment: Throughout chapter 2

Comment: Chapter 2 of the book 'QED'?? It has almost no formulas.

Comment: The ideas are expressed in words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C) \neq P(A \rightarrow C) $

Only $ P(A \rightarrow C) \propto 1/(r_1+r_2)$

$P(A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C)$ is the probability it goes through B on its way to C. If you wanted to examine the case when it does go to $P(A \rightarrow C)$, you could integrate over all possible values of B

Comment: You're right, and this is exactly what we do in QFT. I think the initial scheme written in the book is misleading.